# R.java keeps references to non existing resource id's

Tags: java, android, eclipse

How can I get rid of references to non existing id's in R.java in android project in eclipse. It for resources I have renamed or removed.

What happens sometimes is that I remove a string as an example but the project still shows it as an existing resource. And when I run the app the resource ID from R.java is shown instead. How can I clean these away?

Clean project doesn't work and building it neither.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the R.java. It will be regenerated again on your next build with a non-cached version.